# Как конвертировать из excel в xml на ruby

Tags: xml, ruby, excel

Прошу помочь с алгоритмом.
В общем имеется таблица `excel`, в которой есть несколько листов, например:

```
Лист А
1 | name | address   | phone
2 | Nik  | Jon's st. | 555-555-55

Лист Б
1 | А row number | subject_name | code | country
2 | 2            | Linda        | 2    | USA
3 | 2            | Mag          | 3    | Canada
```

Выходные данные(которые должны получиться в итоге) в xml:

```
<A>
  <name>Nik</name> 
  <address>Jon's sr.</address> 
  <phone>555-555-55</phone>
  <Subjects>
    <B>
      <subject_name>Linda</subject_name>
      <county code="2">USA</country>
    </B>
    <B>
      <subject_name>Mag</subject_name>
      <county code="3">Canada</country>
    </B>
  </Subjects>
</A>
```

код формирования xml примерно должен быть таким:

```
# print_xml.slim
doctype xml
- records.each do |record|
  A
    name= record.name 
    address= record.address 
    phone= record.phone
    Subjects
    - each record.subjects do |subject|
      B
        subject_name= subject.subject_name
        county code="#{subject.code}"= subject.country
```

Элементы должны наследоваться. Каким образом должны наследоваться? Например есть лист "А", в нем какие-то поля, и есть лист "Б", он должен быть дочерним от "А", значит первое поле в листе "Б" делаю такого названия `А row number`(в этом столбике указываем номер строки родительского элемента) и потомков может быть "n-ое" количество. То есть я провел некую аналогию с таблицами в "БД" и ассоциации как в `rails(has_many, belongs_to)`. Вся загвоздка в том, что не получается отсортировать каждый элемент к его родителю(если он есть) по иерархии рекурсивно (просто я никак не пойму). То есть, что я имею ввиду. Я помещаю каждый лист `excel` таблицы в некий массив:

```
def worksheets
  worksheets = []
  @report.worksheets.each do |worksheet|
    worksheets << Worksheet.new(worksheet)
  end
  worksheets
end
```

затем в каждом листе создаю массив строк этого листа(элемент массива - это класс, в котором динамически создаются инстансные переменные, имя которых берется из первой строки каждой колонки):

```
class Worksheet
    attr_accessor :name, :parent, :table

    def initialize(worksheet)
      parent_name = worksheet.row(0)[0].downcase
      @parent = parent_name.split[0].pluralize if parent_name.include?('row number')
      @name = worksheet.name.split[0].downcase.pluralize
      @data = worksheet
      expose_data
    end

    private

      def expose_data
        @table = []
        i = 1
        @data.each 1 do |item|
          @table << WorksheetData.new(@data, i)
          i += 1
        end
      end
  end

  class WorksheetData
    attr_accessor :id

    def initialize(worksheet, row)
      @worksheet = worksheet
      data_mapping row
    end

    private

      def data_mapping(row_num)
        @id = row_num
        j = 0
        @worksheet.row(row_num).each do |col|
          col_name = @worksheet.row(0)[j].downcase.strip.tr(" ", "_")
          ExcelToXmlConverter.define_instance self, col_name
          instance_variable_set("@#{col_name}", @worksheet.row(row_num)[j])
          j += 1
        end
      end
  end
```

здесь я попытался отсортировать каждый элемент каждого листа к его родителю, но пока у меня ничего не получается.

```
    def arrange
      roots = []     
      worksheets.each do |worksheet|
        if worksheet.parent.blank?
          root = Tree::TreeNode.new worksheet.name
          worksheet.table.each do |row|
            node = Tree::TreeNode.new worksheet.name.singularize + row.id.to_s, row
            child_node = find_child(worksheet.name, row.id)
            root << node << child_node
          end
          roots << root
        end
      end   
      roots 
    end

    def find_child(worksheet_name, id)
      result = nil
      worksheets.each do |item|
        if !item.parent.blank? && item.parent == worksheet_name
          result = item.table.select { |arg| arg.instance_variable_get("@#{item.parent}_row_number").to_i == id.to_i + 2 }
          result = Tree::TreeNode.new item.name.singularize + id.to_s, result
        end
      end
      result
    end
```

Вот весь код:

```
class ExcelToXmlConverter
  require 'active_support/inflector'

  class Worksheet
    attr_accessor :name, :parent, :table

    def initialize(worksheet)
      parent_name = worksheet.row(0)[0].downcase
      @parent = parent_name.split[0].pluralize if parent_name.include?('row number')
      @name = worksheet.name.split[0].downcase.pluralize
      @data = worksheet
      expose_data
    end

    private

      def expose_data
        @table = []
        i = 1
        @data.each 1 do |item|
          @table << WorksheetData.new(@data, i)
          i += 1
        end
      end
  end

  class WorksheetData
    attr_accessor :id

    def initialize(worksheet, row)
      @worksheet = worksheet
      data_mapping row
    end

    private

      def data_mapping(row_num)
        @id = row_num
        j = 0
        @worksheet.row(row_num).each do |col|
          col_name = @worksheet.row(0)[j].downcase.strip.tr(" ", "_")
          ExcelToXmlConverter.define_instance self, col_name
          instance_variable_set("@#{col_name}", @worksheet.row(row_num)[j])
          j += 1
        end
      end
  end


  def initialize(excel_file)
    @report = Spreadsheet.open excel_file
  end

  def process
    arrange
  end

  private

    def self.define_instance(klass, name)
      klass.class.send(:define_method, name) {instance_variable_get("@#{name}")}
      klass.class.send(:define_method, "#{name}=") {|arg| instance_variable_set("@#{name}", arg)}
    end

    def arrange
      roots = []     
      worksheets.each do |worksheet|
        if worksheet.parent.blank?
          root = Tree::TreeNode.new worksheet.name
          worksheet.table.each do |row|
            node = Tree::TreeNode.new worksheet.name.singularize + row.id.to_s, row
            child_node = find_child(worksheet.name, row.id)
            root << node << child_node
          end
          roots << root
        end
      end   
      roots 
    end

    def find_child(worksheet_name, id)
      result = nil
      worksheets.each do |item|
        if !item.parent.blank? && item.parent == worksheet_name
          result = item.table.select { |arg| arg.instance_variable_get("@#{item.parent}_row_number").to_i == id.to_i + 2 }
          result = Tree::TreeNode.new item.name.singularize + id.to_s, result
        end
      end
      result
    end

    # создаем массив листов и таблицы excel
    def worksheets
      worksheets = []
      @report.worksheets.each do |worksheet|
        worksheets << Worksheet.new(worksheet)
      end
      worksheets
    end
end
```

Может быть есть совсем иной путь и я слишком замудрил?
Очень нужна ваша помощь. Надеюсь я смог донести свою мысль. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если честно, совсем не понятно что нужно. Ни каким образом должны наследоваться листы, ни что происходит в листинге, ни что конкретно не получается. Предлагаю уточнить эти моменты и оставить в вопросе только минимальный, пригодный для воспроизведения проблемы пример.

Comment: @anoam вы правы. Я исправил вопрос, попытался раскрыть свою мысль в более понятной форме

Comment: Это ассоциация "один-ко-многим". У вас у каждой записи в А есть N записей в Б. Не наследование же.

Comment: @D-side да, я ошибся.